# Where are stored wheels .whl cached files?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

```
$ python3 -m venv ~/venvs/vtest
$ source ~/venvs/vtest/bin/activate
(vtest) $ pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/ab/43e678759326f728de861edbef34b8e2ad1b1490505f20e0d1f0716c3bf4/numpy-1.17.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.17.4
(vtest) $
```

I'm looking for where this wheel `numpy-1.17.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` has been cached ?

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate numpy-1.17.4
$ # nada ;(
```

Documentation https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#wheel-cache tell us that `Pip will read from the subdirectory wheels within the pip cache directory and use any packages found there.`

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from ~/venvs/vtest/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
$
```

To answer Hamza Khurshid numpy is not on ~/.cache/pip/wheels

```
$ find ~/.cache/pip/wheels -name '*.whl' |grep -i numpy
$
```

it look like .cache/pip/wheels is only used for user created wheels not for downloaded wheels, should I use `export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip/cache` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The message

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/ab/43e678759326f728de861edbef34b8e2ad1b1490505f20e0d1f0716c3bf4/numpy-1.17.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

means pip is using the HTTP cache, not the wheel cache (which is only used for locally-built wheels, like you mentioned).

The name of the file in the HTTP cache is the sha224 of the URL being requested.

You can retrieve the file like

```
$ pwd
/home/user/.cache/pip/http
$ find . -name "$(printf 'https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/26/32b8464df2a97e6dd1b656ed26b2c19460
6c16fe163c695a992b36c11cdf/six-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl' | sha224sum - | awk '{print $1}')"
./f/6/0/2/d/f602daffc1b0025a464d60b3e9f8b1f77a4538b550a46d67018978db
```

The format of the file is not stable though, and depends on pip version. For specifics you can see the implementation that's used in the latest [cachecontrol](https://github.com/ionrock/cachecontrol), which pip uses.

If you want to get the actual file, an easier way is to use `pip download`, which will take the file from the cache into your current directory if it matches the URL that would be otherwise downloaded.

Answer (score 8):

Refer to the following path for finding WHL cache files.

In windows,

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\pip\cache
```

In Unix,

```
~/.cache/pip
```

In macOS,

```
~/Library/Caches/pip.
```

Comment: yes I was expecting to found numpy-1.17.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl in ~/.cache/pip/wheels/...