# What is the format of files in `pip-cache/pip/html`?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I'm trying to restore some hard to get dependencies from the `pip` cache. All the files stored in the mentioned directory start with bytes `cc=2`. I would expect something like `.tar.gz` files there, but nope.

I briefly tried to search through `pip` source code, but mostly found code dealing with Wheel archives (which are essentially `.zip` files). I failed to find the code handling the `/http/` subfolder. Not sure if I was looking at the wrong part of the source tree, or wrong pip version.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59240899/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+cache+files+format

Comment: @phd a great find .. if you bother writing an answer with https://github.com/ionrock/cachecontrol/blob/master/cachecontrol/serialize.py#L156, I'll happily accept it;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` uses [`cachecontrol`](https://pypi.org/project/CacheControl/) to load/store its cache files. [The filename is the sha224 of the URL being requested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59240899/7976758).

The code to load the files can be seen [at Gihub](https://github.com/ionrock/cachecontrol/blob/9d5c1f5e71900d200c3bebe995de9f6435d39b72/cachecontrol/serialize.py#L156).

For the particular case of `cc=2`, the data after `cc=2,` (note the comma) can be decoded by

```
cached = json.loads(zlib.decompress(data).decode("utf8"))

# We need to decode the items that we've base64 encoded
cached["response"]["body"] = _b64_decode_bytes(cached["response"]["body"])
cached["response"]["headers"] = dict(
    (_b64_decode_str(k), _b64_decode_str(v))
    for k, v in cached["response"]["headers"].items()
)
cached["response"]["reason"] = _b64_decode_str(cached["response"]["reason"])
cached["vary"] = dict(
    (_b64_decode_str(k), _b64_decode_str(v) if v is not None else v)
    for k, v in cached["vary"].items()
)
```

Comment: Just for my future reference: unwrap all data to `unpacked`: `find var/pip-cache/pip/http -type f | parallel "<{} tail -c+6 | pigz -z -d | jq -r .response.body | base64 -d > unpacked/{/}"`.